# Переброс с приложения в приложение YouTube и открытие в нём определённого видео

Tags: java, android, android-intent, youtube

Как добавить в приложение кнопку, при нажатии которой открывалось бы приложение YouTube на смартфоне, где открывалось бы указанное видео.

То есть, пользователь нажал на кнопку, открылся YouTube с проигрываемым видео (не нужно искать что-то в поиске или ещё где-то, видео само проигрывается).

А если открыть видео в самом activity, не перебрасывая в другое приложение, то будет ли это более затратный в плане ресурсов железа смартфона процесс?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так например:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
 intent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
 intent.putExtra("query", "что-то");
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(intent);
```

и вместо `что-то` можно вставить id нужного вам видеоролика. То есть вам еще нужно как-то его достать и вставить в запрос. Надеюсь что у вас есть id нужного вам видео :)

### update

```
    public static void watchYoutubeVideo(String id) {
    Intent appIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:" + id));
    Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + id));
    try {
        startActivity(appIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        startActivity(webIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Данная кнопка ведёт поиск видео на youtube, но не открывает его

Comment: обновил ответ, попробуйте снова :)